# How to import modules from self created packages(wheel,eggs,tar.gz etc) local/or in artifactory in another python package?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to import modules from self created packages(wheel,eggs,tar.gz etc) local/or in artifactory in another python package? (Possibly a code snippet would be helpful)

Requirement -
There is a developed Python Package abc.whl located on local intranet repository, and another file in second python project /xyz/def.py need to import a module from package abc.whl

Answer (score 1):

I think first you have to install the wheel package.

```
pip install C:/some-dir/some-package.whl
```

If you need to import, you can just do

```
import some-package
```

So in your case

```
pip install abc.whl
import abc
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, just a  follow up question.  Is it possible to install this package(probably located in bin repo/artifactory) through setup or requirement.txt instead of pip?

Comment: You'd still need pip since you'd need to do "pip install -r requirement.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `.egg/.tar` to `*python_installation_path*\Lib\site-packages` using 7-Zip

Comment: what about to import without extraction? python can import from zip. whl is zip